# Javascript log the url of the new tab opened from a javascript click of a button

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code that clicks and opens a link in a new tab. I have to click the button in order to find the url because when you inspect the element, it doesn't contain any value for the href attribute. But when you click, the link opens a new tab. So I need to console.log the link which has been opened and then close it.

Important to mention that I am running the code inside a browser developer console.

Here is my best attempt:

```
// Find the td element containing the "View" button
const tdElement = document.querySelector('td[style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"]');

// Click the "View" button
if (tdElement) {
  tdElement.click();

  // Listen for the load event on the new window
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    console.log('New window opened with URL:', window.location.href);

    // Close
    window.close();
  });
} else {
  console.log('Could not find "View" button');
}
```

UPDATED

```
// Find the td element containing the "View" button
const tdElement = document.querySelector('td[style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"]');

// Click the "View" button
if (tdElement) {
  tdElement.click();

  // Listen to the newly opened tab
  window.addEventListener('focus', () => {
    const openedUrl = window.location.href;
    console.log('Opened URL:', openedUrl);

    // Close the newly opened tab
    window.close();
  }, { once: true });
} else {
  console.log('Could not find "View" button');
}
```

Please help.

Comment: You've to listen events on the opened tab, `window` in your code doesn't refer to the tab.

Comment: I updated it and updated the question but I can't get the console to log the new url

Comment: Again, `window` here is the current window where this script is running, it's not `window` inside the opened tab. I doubt you can even refer to the window in the opened tab, as you said it's a link opening the tab, it's not opened with JS.

Comment: There is no href attribute, so the new window opens with javascript, right?

Comment: Yes it opens with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the new window opens with Javascript and `window.open` is used for it, you can hijack `window.open` so to speak.

The new function stores the url in a variable:

```
let tempUrl = '';

window.open = function(url) {
  tempUrl = url;
}

// Find the td element containing the "View" button
const tdElement = document.querySelector('td[style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"]');

// Click the "View" button
if (tdElement) {
  tdElement.click();
  
  console.log(tempUrl);

} else {
  console.log('Could not find "View" button');
}
```

This way you also save closing the open window again, if you only need the url.

Comment: What do I change if I have multiple links on the same page? So that it works for more than a single link? You saved me!

Comment: Stored them in an array and that worked! Thanks a million. ```let urls = [];

window.open = function(url) {
  urls.push(url);
};

// Find all td elements containing the "View" button
const tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('td[style="cursor: pointer; color: blue;"]');

// Click each "View" button and log the corresponding URL
if (tdElements.length > 0) {
  tdElements.forEach(tdElement => {
    tdElement.click();
    console.log(urls.pop());
  });
} else {
  console.log('Could not find any "View" buttons');
}
```